# SUM of grouped COUNT and add proportion in SQL Query

Tags: mysql

Supposed I have a table with 2 fields:

```
ID  Name
--  -------
1   Alpha
2   Beta
3   Beta
4   Beta
5   Charlie
6   Charlie
```

I want to group them by name, with 'count', and a row 'proportion'

```
Name     Count  proportion
-------  -----  --------
Alpha     1      0.17
Beta      3      0.5
Charlie   2      0.33
```

How would I write a query to add a proportion row beside the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this

```
select
  name,
  count(1) cnt,
  count(1) / (select count(1) from table1) proportion
 from table1
 group by name
```

Here's a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/af9483/3)

Answer (score 0):

select [Name], count(ID) [Count], '...' [proportion] from [table-name] group by [Name]

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved like so:

```
SELECT name, 
       count(name) as counts,
       -- specific name counts divided by total name counts 
       count(name)/( select count(*) from Test ) as proportion
FROM thetable
GROUP BY name;
```